# PHP Header adding multiple times

Tags: php

I have this query:

```
$get_ids = "SELECT unique_id FROM products GROUP BY unique_id LIMIT 10";
$id_results = mysql_query($get_ids);
while($id_row = mysql_fetch_array($id_results))
{
    extract($id_row);
    $all_prods_link[] = $id_row['unique_id']; 
}
```

This will create an array of integers. For each item in the array, I append this to a string, following by a comma:

```
foreach($all_prods_link as $all_prods)
{
    $query_string .= $all_prods.',';
}
```

The result is like: 1,2,3,4,5,6, which is working as intended.

The problem I am having is I am trying to add this to the end of the current URI, and then redirect to this URI eg:

```
$link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '&product_options=' . $query_string;
```

The $link variable looks good:

```
sales_reports.php?date_from=05%2F11%2F2017&date_to=05%2F12%2F2017&pay_status=Paid&submitfilter=Go&prodtype=all&report_type=productreports&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
```

This is exactly what I want, however when I then try to redirect to this link, eg:

```
header("Location: $link");
```

The actual URI I end up with has the $query_string, appended to it multiple times, like so:

```
sales_reports.php?date_from=05%2F11%2F2017&date_to=05%2F12%2F2017&pay_status=Paid&submitfilter=Go&prodtype=all&report_type=productreports&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,&product_options=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
```

As you can see, "&product_options" appears multiple times, followed by the list of integers!

Can the header() function be used this way? or am I doing something horribly wrong!

Comment: That is not the fault of the `header` function ... make a debug output of your $link variable right before that, and check what it contains.

Comment: _“The problem I am having is I am trying to add this to the end of the current URI”_ - and does this current URL contain `&product_options=...` already? Then you should not be surprised to get it multiple times, if you just append to the end of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get and change URL variable PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036775/how-to-get-and-change-url-variable-php)

Comment: `foreach($all_prods_link as $all_prods)
{
    $query_string .= $all_prods.',';
}` err, you should be using [*`implode()`*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for this.

Comment: @CBroe the $link variable actually contains exactly what I need, please see the section of my post that starts "The $link variable looks good:", can you tell me why header("Location: $link"); doesn't go to $link exactly?

Comment: Again, it is not `header` that’s messing this up, that is impossible. And as long as you show only single lines of code at a time, we can’t possible tell you where exactly it goes wrong, or at what point you perhaps let yourself got fooled by your debug outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of multiple redirect each time you load the page, php will *append* product_options rather than replacing it.

```
<?php

// Parse all request components
$request = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// Parse incoming query sting to array
parse_str($request['query'], $queryArray);

// replace or add product_options
$queryArray['product_options'] = $query_string;

// rebuild the query
$newQueryString = http_build_query($queryArray);

$link = $request['path']. '?' . $newQueryString;

header("Location: $link");
```