# make a link with request_uri

Tags: php

I have a form that sends me an e-mail when a form is submitted. I added a hidden field that shows which URL the form has been submitted from. This code:

```
add_filter('frm_get_default_value', 'my_custom_default_value', 10, 2);
    function my_custom_default_value($new_value, $field){
        if($field->id == 84){ //ID of the hidden field
            $new_value = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //stores the value of the URL
    }
return $new_value;
}
```

is printing in my e-mail: `/tour/australia`

But I would like the printed material as a link like this instead: https://example.com/tour/australia. I tried to solve this with the below code:

```
add_filter('frm_get_default_value', 'my_custom_default_value', 10, 2);
    function my_custom_default_value($new_value, $field){
        if($field->id == 84){ //ID of the hidden field
            $new_value = $_SERVER['<a href="https://example.com">REQUEST_URI</a>']; //stores the value of the URL
    }
return $new_value;
}
```

But I could not get anything to print with this code. Can someone help me solve this?

Best regards

Comment: I believe this could help you. [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036775/how-to-get-and-change-url-variable-php)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just tried the different suggestions there, but I cannot make it work. I stil get the same printed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] to get the hostname, and add it to the other one.  like so:

```
$new_value = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

You may need to add a / in there.  This is from memory and Im not able to test at the moment.